# Knockout nested component using $componentTemplateNodes results in wrong viewModel

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to access the view model of a nested component from the page view model.

This is the template:

```
<collapse-panel>
    <custom-component data-bind="viewModel: $root.customComponentVM">
    </custom-component>
</collapse-panel>
```

The template for the collapse-panel component:

```
<div class="collapse panel-collapse" data-bind="
    template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes }">
</div>
```

In the custom-component, I added the custom binding named viewModel using the following typescript code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers["viewModel"] = {
    init: (element: any,
        valueAccessor: () => KnockoutObservable<any>,
        allBindingsAccessor: KnockoutAllBindingsAccessor,
        viewModel: any,
        bindingContext: KnockoutBindingContext): void => {
        valueAccessor()(viewModel);
    }
};
```

My issue is that the viewModel object in the init function should be the CustomElementVM, but instead I get the CollapsePanelVM.

This is what I get when adding a breakpoint in the init method:

```
element              //the expected custom-element
viewModel            //the incorrect CollapsePanelVM
ko.dataFor(element)  //also returns the incorrect CollapsePanelVM
```

I have also tried binding the custom-element using the following syntax:

```
<div data-bind="component: {name: 'custom-component' ...
```

And also binding the $componentTemplateNodes using the Knockout comment syntax as well:

```
<div class="collapse panel-collapse">
    <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

However I still get the wrong viewModel. Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug in Knockout?
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `valueAccessor()` return the `viewModel` you're looking for? the `viewModel` provided by knockout via the parameter refers to the `$data` in which the data-bind was bound.

Comment: valueAccessor() returns a minified js function which returns the knockout observable. It is unfortunately not the viewModel I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding handler is being executed in the context of the `collapse-panel` component because that is what it is *inside*. The context of a tag applies inside it, and not to the tag itself (note, for example, how the `if` binding works - the tag is always there, but its contents may not be).

If you want the `viewModel` binding to be executed in the context of `custom-component`, make that binding on a tag in the template for `custom-component`.

If you want the parent to be able to set up a component's viewmodel, you should [use `params`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html).

> `params` — an object that will be passed on to the component. Typically
>   this is a key-value object containing multiple parameters, and is
>   typically received by the component’s viewmodel constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add the binding in the custom-component template as this component is used multiple times in the same page. They would conflict with each other. Would there be a way to have a `foreach: $componentTemplateNodes, as: 'item'` followed by something like `<div data-bind="template: {data: item}"></div>` to apply the right context to children nodes?

Comment: @skety It sounds to me like you want to pass `params` to the components. Within the component's viewmodel constructor, you can use the `params` to customize the vm. That may make the viewmodel binding handler unnecessary.

Comment: I guess I could pass the page's view model to a parameter and have the component register itself to it. You are right that should work. Many thanks.